# How to compose actions while accessing the request body?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to compose actions, while accessing the body in every action to a different part?
So if for example, I have a json that looks like this:

```
{
   "compayId": 123,
   "reason": "some_reason",
   "date": "2017-01-01",
   "roles": ["1", "2"]
}
```

I want to access the "companyId" and "reason" in the audit action, while accessing the "date" and "roles" in the actual action.
So I created something like this, which doesn't work of course..

```
trait Audit { def auditDao: AuditDao
 def audit[A](action: Action[A]) = Action.async(action.parser) { implicit request => {
   action(request).flatMap( r => 
       Json.toJson(request.body.asInstanceOf[RawBuffer].asBytes().get.toArray).validate[AuditLog].fold( //The instanceOf is ugly, and will not work, it's just for the example
           errors => errorsToFutureResult(errors)(request),
           audit => auditDao.save(audit).map(_ => r)
       )
   }
  }
}
```

And then wrap my endpoint with the audit method:

```
def get() = audit(Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.raw) { (request: Request[RawBuffer]) =>
 Json.toJson(request.body.asBytes().get.toArray).validate[Roles].fold( 
           errors => errorsToFutureResult(errors)(request),
           roles => //Do stuff with the roles...
       )
})
```

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Take a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActionsComposition